# Prisma and Sqlite 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sqlite, next.js

I have set up Prisma with Sqlite in my next.js app, I've set the table Movies in the Prisma scheme

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:dev.db"
}
model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
  image String?
  email String? @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  hashedPassword String?
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  sessions Session[]
  accounts Account[]
  favoriteIds String?
  invite String
}

model Account {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId             Int   
  type               String
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String
  refresh_token      String?  
  access_token       String?  
  expires_at         Int?
  token_type         String?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String?  
  session_state      String?
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  sessionToken String @unique
  userId Int 
  expires DateTime
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model VerificationToken {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime
  @@unique([identifier, token])
}

model Movie {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  title String
  description String
  videoUrl String
  thumbnailUrl String
  genre String
  duration String
}
```

**And I have populated the table Movies with some urls and demo data, then I've created some files and a player button that creates a route to play that specific movie by taking its id
**
[movieId].ts

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import prismadb from '@/lib/prismadb';
import serverAuth from "@/lib/serverAuth";

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    return res.status(405).end();
  }

  try {
  
    await serverAuth(req, res);

    const { movieId } = req.query;

    if (!movieId) {
      throw new Error('Missing Id');
    }

    if (isNaN(parseInt(movieId as string, 10))) {
      throw new Error('Invalid Id');
    }    

    const movies = await prismadb.movie.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: Number(movieId).toString()
      }
    });

    console.log(`Error here: ${movieId}`);

    return res.status(200).json(movies);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error here ${error}`);
    return res.status(500).end();
  }
}
```

useMovie.ts

```
import useSwr from 'swr'
import fetcher from '@/lib/fetcher';

const useMovie = (id?: number | string) => {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSwr(id ? `/api/movies/${id}` : null, fetcher, {
    revalidateIfStale: false,
    revalidateOnFocus: false,
    revalidateOnReconnect: false,
  });
  return {
    data,
    error,
    isLoading
  }
};

export default useMovie;
```

PlayButton.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { PlayIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/solid';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

interface PlayButtonProps {
  movieId: number;
}

const PlayButton: React.FC<PlayButtonProps> = ({ movieId }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <button 
      onClick={() => router.push(`/watch/${movieId}`)}
      className="
        bg-white 
        rounded-md 
        py-1 md:py-2 
        px-2 md:px-4
        w-auto 
        text-xs lg:text-lg 
        font-semibold
        flex
        flex-row
        items-center
        hover:bg-neutral-300
        transition
        "
      >
        <PlayIcon className="w-4 md:w-7 text-black mr-1" />
        Play
    </button>
  );
}

export default PlayButton;
```

and this is my fetcher.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';

const fetcher = (url: string) => axios.get(url).then(res => res.data);

export default fetcher;
```

The error i get in the console is this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH9Kg.png)

**I tried to use MangoDB and it works but i thought since this is a simple project application to use a sqlite database just to test it out**